# Having trouble with settings terms as array in pre_get_posts

Tags: pre-get-posts

I am trying to filter posts based on a custom field I have set up for a user.  `allowed_categories` is a multiselect custom field on the add new/edit user page that lets the admin choose which terms in a taxonomy the user has access to.  In this case the taxonomy is `product_cat`.  I added a user and chose some terms, that is working fine.  I wrote a function that should get the product categories the user is assigned to and filters returned results based on those values.  Problem is it is not working? Probably overlooking something simple here..

What is returned when I print the `allowed_categories` from the current user.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
)
```

My `pre_get_posts` action

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        $allowedCats = get_field('allowed_categories', 'user_' . $user->ID);

        if( isset($cats) && $cats > 0) {
            $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $allowedCats,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )));
        }

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `tax_query` block of code like below-

```
$q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'term_id', // Here it would be 'term_id' instead of only 'ID'.
    'terms' => $allowedCats,
    'operator' => 'IN' // May be it would be 'IN' in stead of 'NOT IN'. Cause you are passing allowed product categories.
)));
```

Hope that helps.